# How do I detect that Java Util Logging is already configured?

Tags: java, logging

I have some code that is sometimes called from my own Main method and sometimes it is embedded within someone else's program. When configuring logging, I want to be able to detect that someone has already configured Java Util Logging and if they have then I want to skip my configuration. I have this method:

```
public static boolean isLoggingAlreadyConfigured(){        
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("");
    Handler[] handlers = logger.getHandlers();
    return handlers != null && handlers.length > 1;
}
```

But I think it is unreliable.

Can you suggest something better?

Comment: It's a while since I wrote this code... and in the stark light of SO.. now i'm wondering why I have handlers.length > 1 instead of 0?!

Comment: Did a quick test... it's because there is a default handler already configured on the root logger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is that java.util logging is *always* configured.

The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html) for `LogManager` says that it is a global object that is created automatically, and that it is configured automatically based either on what a couple of system properties say, or (if the properties are not set) using a built-in logging properties configuration.  (Refer to the javadoc for details).  The bottom line is that you won't ever see the logger in an "unconfigured" state.

You could figure out what a JRE's built-in logging properties configuration says by default, and test to see if the current configuration is different.  But this approach has some problems:

- The JRE's built-in config could have been tweaked (per the javadoc).
- Different JRE releases could have defaults (hypothetically ...).

and most important

- You probably cannot programmatically distinguish *some* application-specific configurations from the default configurations.